# fragment not being removed

Tags: java, android

After many days of trying to find a solution for having a dual pane fragment along with tabs, i gave up and made my own listview that's in a an x-large layout for tablets, and having only fragments to manage my tabs. All my code works except one part, where i am trying to remove the old fragment in the tab and create a new fragment based on the item clicked in the list.

Here is where the fragments for the tabs are generated:

```
public class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
   public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
       super(fm);                                 
    }
   //THESE FRAGMENTS ARE GENERATED WITH TABS AT START

 @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int i) {
     switch (i) {     
     case 0:
            return new DescriptionFragment();
     case 1:
      return new ImagesFragment();
     default:
            return new DescriptionFragment();
  }
}
```

where i add fragments from a listview click:

```
public  void addfragment() {   
//THIS FRAGMENT GOES ON TOP AFTER LISTVIEW CLICK
    kick_activity.this.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    DescriptionFragment fragment = new DescriptionFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();
}
```

my DescriptionFragment fragment:

```
 public static class DescriptionFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_description, container, false);  
        text = ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.description));         
        text.setText(Html.fromHtml(description_text));
        return rootView;
 }
```

I know what i'm doing wrong, I just don't know how to fix it. It seems that the fragment from getItem() is created and when i click on my listview and addfragment() is called, it overlays due to the fragments not being linked. What can i place in 'case 0' instead of 'return new DescriptionFragment' so that all my fragments are linked and don't overlay?

Note - when i try and use ft.repalce in getItem() the app crashes and according to the LogCat, it cannot find R.id.container, so i cannot simply move that code in.

Thanks in advance for your help, i will greatly appreciate any solutions as I have been stuck on this for quite a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly for each list item you want to create / set a corresponding Detail and Image fragment which will be hosted in the FragmentPagerAdapter?

If so, when a list item is clicked you could call:-

```
mPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), listItemPosition);
```

When a list item is clicked, and let the FragmentPagerAdapter manage the fragments.

You'd also need to change the adapter to take the list item position and use accordingly. Such as:-

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int mPosition;
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int position) {
        super(fm);
        mPosition = position;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please true to use my running code and addFragment method not usable.

public class ViewPagerExample extends FragmentActivity

{
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private static Activity activity;

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    activity = this;
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
```

@Override
 public Fragment getItem(int i) {
     switch (i) {
     case 0:
            return new DescriptionFragment();
     case 1:
      return new ImagesFragment();
     default:
            return new DescriptionFragment();
  }

}

}

}